# Ros Navigation Stack

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to ask about the Navigation Stack, i have been following (https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-set-up-the-ros-navigation-stack-on-a-robot/) tutorial

My question is can i complete the Navigation process without IMU sensor and sensor fusion and if so what is required from me would appreciate it if someone looked inside the tutorial in odom publishing would deleting the imu and sensor fusion launch files be enough or do i need to do more?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402024/ros-navigation-stack/) by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add something that publishes the odometry.

Odometry is telling navigation how much your robot has moved (or how much it thinks it has moved). If you don't have that, navigation assumes the robot isn't actually moving.

As for how you would do that (to catch that question in advance) it matters a lot what you're actually using as a robot. Are you using a Gazebo simulation? Then you're probably using the `gazebo_ros` `diff_drive_controller`. In that case it's as simple as setting the parameter `publishOdomTF` to true.

If you're using a physical robot, then the question is "how are you moving it". If you're using `ros_control`, you need to tell it to publish the odometry (again, by changing a parameter).

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on 2022-06-09**:
Yes a physical robot , i have been publishing odometry from Arduino to ros via encoders , it delivers the speed of the robot to ros is that enough or does the navigation stack need the encoder ticks of left and right wheels ? I move the robot using the cmd topic with teleop and all that

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-06-09**:
Navigation only needs the odometry (which is the speed/rotation of the *robot*). It does not need the encoder ticks or the individual speeds of each wheel.

What it does need, is for the odometry to be published in the TF tree (take a look at the tf tree from [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/316037/tf-not-moving-in-navigation-stack/)). Something needs to publish that TF. I know `ros_control` can easily do that, but I don't know if that's what you're currently using.

If it's not, you'll need to publish the TF yourself, although it might be less of a headache to switch to using `ros_control` over publishing the TF yourself. Are you using a self built robot, or one that's available from somewhere?

**Comment by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on 2022-06-09**:
I see, no its a self built robot for graduation project, this is the first time i am hearing about ros_control will take a look at it and try to implement it if possible

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-06-09**:
It's quite useful. Right now, I'm assuming you've written a piece of code that takes the `cmd_vel` and calculates the speed for each wheel.

If you use `ros_control` and  you use the correct controller (diff_drive/ackermann/holonomic) and then configure them (setting wheel separation, wheel radius) it will calculate the speed for each wheel AND if you give it the speed of each wheel back, it will calculate the odometry and publish/broadcast the tf for you.

There are also other things you can set in `ros_control` like the max velocity, max acceleration, such like that.

If you've got a diff drive robot, you can take a look at the [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller).